# mdadm root partition raid 1 fails intermittently

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

For a while I've been setting all servers up with software RAID 1 root and boot partitions in order to minimize downtime in case of disk failure.  On install I set up

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata 1.0 --raid-devices=2 --level=1 /dev/sd[ab]1
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --raid-devices=2 --level=1 /dev/sd[ab]2
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/md0
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1
```

and then set these up in fstab as /boot and /, respectively.  Of course EFI can't read a software RAID 1 partition, so the EFI boot devices are /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 *individually*.  The initramfs is set up to know about mdadm, so / is immediately mounted as a /dev/md1 raid partition, and /dev/md0 is mirrored after boot, keeping `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` synchronized.  I've been setting systems up like this for years and have never had any problems.

Until recently, when I configured a backup server with 26 HBA disks.  `/dev/sdy` and `/dev/sdz` are the SSD disks I used for `/` and `/boot`.  Most of the time the system boots fine.  Intermittently, however, on reboot the system crashes complaining that "the superblock on `/dev/md1` is corrupted" and to "try running e2fsck -b 8198 etc.) to fix the problem.  However, there is nothing wrong with the superblock on /dev/md1. I can boot from a USB stick and mount /`dev/md1` with no problem, and `e2fsck` returns no errors on the device.  I'm at a loss for what could be causing this (other than intermittent hardware issues or perhaps flaky firmware).  I briefly considered that it could be the large number of disks in the system combined with how `mdadm` assembles raids by default (namely by scanning through partitions looking for RAID superblocks), but then realized this directive lives in /etc/mdadm.conf, which can't be read until after / is already mounted, which is the problem in the first place.

Has anyone else ever seen this problem or know of a solution?

Comment: "but then realized this directive lives in /etc/mdadm.conf, which can't be read until after / is already mounted" `mdadm.conf` is very likely copied to your initramfs. I'd suggest checking `cat /proc/mdstat` after the initramfs dies if possible (check if you can configure it to dump you to an emergency shell with busybox)—see if the array was actually assembled. Also look through the messages carefully, sometimes there are ten, fifteen lines after the actual failure hiding it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, especially the observation that mdadm.conf is being copied to initramfs (but of course -- why didn't I think of this?).  After initramfs dies, if I try to <Ctrl>-d through to a prompt I get a kernel panic and the system is just frozen (so, in particular, I can't check /proc/mdstat).  However, based on your input, let me modify /etc/mdadm.conf (I'm not sure how yet), and then rebuild the initramfs.  I can usually get it to crash every 4-6 reboots, so it shouldn't be hard to test this hypothesis.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'd not guess control-D to get a prompt—normally that'd give up on the prompt. What's it asking you that you're control-D'ing? At least the Debian one can be configured to eventually just dump you to a shell prompt.

Comment: I'll check, but I don't think I can do anything other than <Ctrl>-d from the "failed to mount / filesystem" prompt.  <Ctrl>-d tells initramfs to continue the boot process anyway, which usually gets you to a functional prompt but in this case results in a kernel panic.

Comment: So, you were right.  I can `cat /proc/mdstat` when the system is in a failed to boot state, and both mdadm raids show up there.  The boot partition is listed as `/dev/md127` instead of `/dev/md0` for some reason, but `/dev/md1` is definitely there.  I'm starting to think I have a firmware problem.

Comment: What kind of drives are those? A lot of times drive order isn't guaranteed, especially between multiple controllers. Also, I'd suggest you can use that shell to look for what went wrong, e.g., at minimum use it to capture dmesg to a USB stick and compare it to a successful boot.

Comment: 24 of the drives are Seagate Archive HDD 8TB SATA drives, the other 2 are some kind of enterprise grade 225GB SSD.   The SSDs seems to consistently be sdy and sdz, but you're almost certainly correct that the top 24 disks were probably moving around.  I could get ZFS to automatically mount my zpool until I redefined it using /dev/disk/by-id (I was using the short device name previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using **systemd-boot** as my UEFI boot manager (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot), and systemd-boot requires that you provide *loader configuration entries* which provide information about which kernel/initramfs file to boot as well as options which are passed as kernel boot parameters.  One of these options specifies the root device:

```
# cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=UUID=acf7e0be-5723-478e-aad6-80af6eb82a92 rw ipv6.disable=1
```

I had originally set the root device to be `root=/dev/md1`, as I normally do, but this system includes 26 HBA disks, and I think the system was getting confused about its disk device naming.  In any case, changing the root to
`root=UUID=acf7e0be-5723-478e-aad6-80af6eb82a92` as illustrated above has resolved this issue, and the system now boots correctly every time.