# A complete OS mirror using Ubuntu 17.04 RAID1 + EFI

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

Does any one know how to setup a RAID1 mirrored Ubuntu 17.04 Server via the installer program? I want to have the complete system mirrored, including the EFI partion, so if one disk fails, I can still boot with the other.

I am trying to accomplish what has been outlined here: [RAID1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325238/mdadm-root-partition-raid-1-fails-intermittently), but I must  be omitting some unmentioned setup steps because the installer won't let me enter the fat32 formatted md0 as /boot

I have also tried entering the commands at a terminal during the installation, but the resulting system is un-bootable.